# Radius of curvature book

Tags: calculus, reference-request

Please provide a pdf file of some standard calculus book which contains radius of curvature as a unit. I am very new to this course. Solved example related to radius of curvature is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Useful google searches: ["radius of curvature" + calculus + archive.org](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22radius+of+curvature%22+calculus+archive.org) AND [freely available google-books search for "radius of curvature" + calculus](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22radius+of+curvature%22+calculus&tbm=bks&tbs=bkv:r). And of course you could simply browse books at a nearby library, if one is available.